# Format mysql Table to bring in Attendace Sheet Format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have data in my mysql table in the following format as below image,
[image: mysql table]

What i am trying to do is to generate the attendance report for a month as in below format.

[image: required format]

I am newbie, suggest me how can i perform this.

Comment: **suggest me how can i perform this.** - First, tell us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have data in your database. now you want to show the data in front end by customizing it. so which technology you are using like AWT,Swing, JSP, jsf , Spring MVC or whatever.(in java)
You have to create front-end like tables or columns as you shown in an image.
so for that you have to configure and place the proper placeholder. you have to do mappings and customization also.

First let me know which technology you want to use.

Comment: will u please reply?